# I want to know why Phpmailer fails to send email occasionally

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

So I have this function:

```
$toAddress = $sendTo;
try {
    $mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
    $mail->Host = self::$host;
    $mail->Port = 587;//self::$port; // or 587
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->CharSet = self::$charset;
    $mail->Username = self::$username;
    $mail->Password = self::$password;
    $mail->SetFrom(self::$from, self::$fromAlias);
    $mail->Subject = trim("Here's your csv.");
    $mail->Body = trim("Thank you for using List Master Application. Please download your csv on this link. <a href='http://36.55.238.182:81/pagination/download?file=".$fileName."'>Here!</a>");
    if(is_array($toAddress))
    {
        foreach($toAddress as $to_line)
        {
            $mail->AddAddress($to_line);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $mail->AddAddress($toAddress);
    }

    if ($mail->send())
    {
          log_message('debug', 'sucessfully send email to ' . $sendTo);
          return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
         log_message('debug', 'Failed to send email to ' . $sendTo);
         log_message('debug', 'Failed message is : ' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
         return FALSE;
    }

    } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
          log_message('debug', $e->errorMessage()); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
    } catch (Exception $e) {
          log_message('debug', $e->getMessage()); //Boring error messages from anything else!
    }
```

I have been told previously that I need to upgrade the PhpMailer.

But I need to know why does it sometimes send successfully, and also it sometimes fail in this phpmailer 5.2 version.

Could there be any mail() settings missing?

Is there any reason for it to time-out?

Could it be that server mail regarded it as spam mail?

It's good that mostly it sends successfully but when it fails, I check the log and it gives me this:

```
The following From address failed: test.mymail@gmail.com : Called Mail() without being connected
```

Why is this showing when email fails to send?

What does this mean?

Comment: This is covered [in the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#smtp-error-could-not-connect-to-smtp-host), as I said the last time you asked. The best way to solve this is not to send directly, but install a local mail server and relay through that. Mail servers are specifically designed to cope with intermittent connections, and it's also by far the fastest way to handle sending email during page submissions in your app. This is also covered in the guide and other articles in the PHPMailer wiki.

Comment: Also you're still basing your code on an obsolete example (even for 5.2), and because you've not enabled exceptions (by passing `true` to the constructor), your try/catch will do nothing.

Comment: @Synchro have you any links that I can base latest code for sending mail?

Comment: This really isn't rocket science you know: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer